# Restricting TypeScript generic using another generic in JSDoc

Tags: typescript, generics, jsdoc

I was wondering if one can refer to the first generic type from the second one using JSDoc comments, e.g. `utility-types` package defines `Optional<T, K>` as:

```
type Optional<T extends object, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>;
```

I tried to recreate this type in JSDoc comments with:

```js
/**
 * @template {object} T
 * @template {keyof T} K
 *
 * @typedef {Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>} Optional
 */
```

This code doesn't work, and TypeScript outputs `TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.` at the second `@template`. To make this type work properly, `K` **has** to be restricted, as `Pick<T, K>` requires `K` to be `keyof T`.

My TypeScript version is 4.3.5

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a temporary workaround that isn't quite the same but does the job:

```
/**
 * @template {object} T
 * @template K
 *
 * @typedef {K extends keyof T ? Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>> : never} Optional
 */
```

Answers regarding the original problem are still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

COnsider next example:

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @template {keyof T} K
 * @typedef {Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>} Optional SpecialType - creates a new type named 'SpecialType'
 */

/**
 * @template T
 * @template {keyof T} K 
 * @param {T} obj
 * @param {K} key
 * @return {Optional<T,K>}
 */
function optional(obj, key) {
    return x;
}

const result = optional({ age: 42 },'age')
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that this solution introduces an actual function instead of just a type, which is redundant and probably incorrect (what is `x`?)

Comment: Then just remove the function? I have defined Optional type. Whats the problem?

Comment: Then your unconstrained type definition throws errors both when defined using JSDoc comments or as a TypeScript type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwDwBUA0UA0gHxQC8sAtgsLgSVAGRQAKaATopliwgMYBrOkWLEA3EA

Comment: That's what I tried earlier (see the question), and it seems like TypeScript can't see `T` at this point yet, [check this image](https://i.imgur.com/gvbagt7.png).